# Python how to join list of lists using join function

Tags: python

I am new to Python. Have a question regarding join function.

```
masterlist = [
    ('ap172', ['33', '212-583-1173', '19 Boxer Rd.', 'New York', 'NY', '10005']),
    ('axe99', ['42', '212-582-5959', '315 W. 115th Street, Apt. 11B', 'New York', 'NY', '10027'])
]
```

I want to print each element of list delimited by pipe.

If I try:

```
for i in masterlist:
    mystring = '|'.join(i)                                      
    print mystring
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, list found
```

So I am trying:

```
for i in masterlist:
    mystring = i[0] 
    mystring += '|'.join(i[1])                                  
    print mystring
```

and I get:

```
ap17233|212-583-1173|19 Boxer Rd.|New York|NY|10005
axe9942|212-582-5959|315 W. 115th Street, Apt. 11B|New York|NY|10027
```

So it works but would like to know if there is a better way to join the above masterlist using join function?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you meant to do, but the first two elements, ie 'ap172' and '33', aren't being separated by a pipe.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the first two elements should be separated.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think splitting up the tuples in the for loop would be cleaner.

```
for identifier, data in masterlist:
     print "%s%s" %(identifier, '|'.join(data))
```

Comment: Hi,                                                                   To get what I was trying I modified the last statement to:           print "%s%s%s" %(identifier, '|', '|'.join(data))                               Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain
for symbol, items in masterlist:
    print "|".join(chain( [symbol], items))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get what you got you can try

```
for i in masterlist:
    print i[0] + '|'.join(i[1])
```

To get what I think your after you can try this

```
for i in masterlist:
    print i[0] + '|' + '|'.join(i[1])
```

There are many many ways to do this, these are just 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in masterlist:
    print '|'.join([i[0]] + i[1])
```